# Force SSL (HTTPS) only for checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to use WooCommerce's "Force secure checkout" and "Force HTTP" features to force HTTPS only on checkout page. Following this instructions- [ssl-and-https](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/ssl-and-https/) and [Checkout Process](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/#checkout-process).
Once I done this settings, its forcing checkout page on HTTPS but when I go back to other pages they also starts showing on HTTPS. I only want checkout page to be displayed on HTTPS, and moving out of this page automatically should display on HTTP.

I also try to change `.htaccess` file as given [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129/is-there-a-way-to-force-ssl-on-certain-pages), but it does't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to secure all your pages?

Comment: @Tom, its ecommerce website and client doesn't want to put all pages on https only the checkout page.

Comment: Then I hope that website doesn't manage user accounts or personal data, and have https for the back-end.

Comment: it manages, but it seems https put extra latency on the website loading or slower down the performance, and other pages are simply content/products are displaying.

Comment: With SPDY/http2, HTTPS is faster than HTTP. So you leave passwords without encryption on the network? I hope none of your client reuse their passwords, or they can thank you if they are hacked. The only secure way to handle user account is with http on *all* the webpage, with HSTS to prevent MiTM.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In your WordPress administrator dashboard, go to Settings -> General and change both URLs to have http:// rather than https://.

Step 2: These site asset files can easily be corrected by fixing the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file found at the root of your WordPress application.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Step 3: check this checkbox[image]

Comment: How can I do it in the latest version of WC?